# Unix - Print Common Lines side by side

Tags: unix, awk

I want to compare 2 unsorted files and print the common lines side by side

File1

a 1 2
b 2 4
c 1 4
e 1 2

File2
a 0 3
c 1 4
d 3 4
b 2 4

output1

a 1 2 0 3
b 2 4 2 4
c 1 4 1 4

output2
a 1 2 0 3
b 2 4 2 4
c 1 4 1 4
d     3 4
e 1 2

I can achieve using Join but i want to find a command using awk.

Can we do it without sorting the file and using awk to get the output1 and output2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR {line[$1]=$0; next} 
    $1 in line {
        f2fields = gensub($1 FS, "", 1)
        print line[$1], f2fields > "output1"
        print line[$1], f2fields > "output2"
        seen[$1]++
        next
    } 
    {print > "output2"} 
    END { for (key in line) if (!(key in seen)) print line[key] > "output2" }
' file1 file2

$ cat output1
a 1 2 0 3
c 1 4 1 4
b 2 4 2 4

$ cat output2
a 1 2 0 3
c 1 4 1 4
d 3 4
b 2 4 2 4
e 1 2
```

The order of the output{1,2} files is determined by 1) the order of the records of file2, then 2) the records of file1 not appearing in file2 are output "randomly" (in hash order).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the command but it dint work for me. I modified f2fileds and tried for the output1 , but the second file is printed with the key column.    
Can you please advise on how to fetch the second file from the second column alone?    
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{f2=$0; print a[$1],f2;next} ' file1 file2  > output1    
   $ cat output1  
   a 1 2 a 0 3  
   c 1 4 c 1 4  
   b 2 4 b 2 4

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with GNU awk like this:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" }

FNR == NR { lines[$1] = $0; next }
FNR != NR { if( $1 in lines ) {
              k = $1
              # strip unnecessary key $1 from $0
              $1 = ""
              lines[ k ] = lines[ k ] $0
            }
            else lines[$1] = $0;
          }

END { for( k in lines ) print lines[ k ] }
```

use it like this: `awk -f script.awk file1 file2`

The `PROCINFO` thing is special to gnu awk. If you do not need sorting and dont have gnu awk, you can comment out the first line and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the command but it dint work for me. I modified f2fileds and tried for the output1 , but the second file is printed with the key column.    
Can you please advise on how to fetch the second file from the second column alone?    
awk -F "," 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{f2=$0; print a[$1],f2;next} ' file1 file2  > output1      
$ cat output1    
a 1 2 a 0 3  
c 1 4 c 1 4  
b 2 4 b 2 4

Comment: @Apama removing the key for file two is done in the `FNR != NR` action by setting `$1= ""` and then using `$0`. At least in GNU awk $0 gets updated and after that consists of the original `$2 ... $5`. If that does not work use: `lines[ k ] = lines[ k ] $2 $3 $4 $5` instead.  
Btw you get output1 by commenting out the else part.

Comment: @Apama in your first comment you use ` awk -F ","` that implies comma field separator. The examples in the question are separated by space, so I am not sure if you need the `-F ","` part or not.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was typo due to the different files tested. However the FS dint cause the issue for me. I was able to resolve the problem with printing from $2.